# With Git, how do I organize code so that every developer gets their own branch (or similar) to test out and develop their own code?

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

I starting to get into Git and got into it for more convenient development.

I am working on an [independent video game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indie_game) with a small team, and I want to have a branch for each developer. When ready we would transfer to the master branch. The problem is that branches are just pointers for commits (I believe?) so with each developer working on different parts of the code (algorithms, GUIs, math, etc.), how will we develop separately?

With branches, the files still go to each other even for test branches with placeholders, and when the others synchronise, their files still get the files from the test branch.

I heard about orphan branches; do those have separate files from each other? I am OK with not using branches, but what do you think is the best way for me to go with this?

Comment: Just a few notes: you probably don't want to have a branch for each developer, but for each feature. Give [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/centralized-workflow) a read; it describes different git branching workflows.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot more sense, so branches for features, if I don't want to be disturbed by other developer features we can have different forks, but I don't think we need that right now. I do have a few more questions. **1.** Should I have my local repo on as my Eclipse project updates are instantly ready to commit or not. **2.** Can I see all forks as the Team admin on bitbucket even though their forked repos are private?

Comment: Your understanding of branches is a bit misleading. Branches are branches. They contain code history that don't interact with each other except when the branch was first split from its parent (this can be constantly modified via rebase) and when the branch is merged (either the branch is merged to another branch or another branch is merged to it). Tags are pointers to commits.

Answer (score 2):

**You don't do this at all.**

In Git, every developer even has her own **repository** (at least one) where she works out new features. Once she's done, she could publish her features to your blessed upstream repo where her repo was cloned from.

Have a read at the [Distributed Workflows](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows) chapter of the [Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). This will give you a lot of useful insights to how things work with Git.

Comment: Would it be effective to have every one have their own forked repo, because sometimes certain features are unfinished and other people would like to work without those features.